# Center input search with the menu bar

Tags: html, css

I have a menu bar with Home // Novedades // Categorias // Profile with an specify design and I want to put an input type search in middle of them

I do this:

Html:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul id="navmenu">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Novedades</a></li>
        <li><input type="search" placeholder="Buscar"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categorías <span class="darrow">▼</span></a>
            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="#">Acción</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Aventuras</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile <span class="darrow">▼</span></a>
            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4.2 <span class="rarrow">▶</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub2">
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 4.2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 4.2.2</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
```

And the Css:

```
.menu {
    height: 35px;
    width: auto;
    background: url("../img/slash-layer.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% #BB1010;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: apple;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

#letra {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: apple;
}

#registrarse {
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #BB1010;
    font-family: apple;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    max-width: 660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul#navmenu li {
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 li {
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
    background-color: #9D9D9D;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
    background-color: #9D9D9D;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 126px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display: block;
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
    display: block;
}
.darrow {
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 4px;
}
.rarrow {
    font-size: 13pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 4px;
}
```

So when I put the input it doesn't have design and does that the profile goes down the menu bar.

How can I put the input search in the middle with the same design and all in order?

Comment: You're looking to put the search bar in between Novedades and Profile?

Comment: Between Novedades and Categorias

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the max width in this part of the CSS

```
ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
   list-style-type: none;
   /*max-width: 660px;*/
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/Xero1212/g2Y77/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it works!

```
.busca {
    font-family: apple;
    font-size: 16pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It associates an Id to the input and then I can put the same design as the others!

Thanks for all